Create view with Dbeaver
I need to create a SQL view in DB2 using dbeaver.
This view will use variables that are results of other SQL queries run upstream.
Example query 1:
select champs1 
from table1 

===> store value in var1
Use of this variable :
select * 
from table2 
where field2 > MMRGDT>(year(current date - var1 days)*10000 + month(current date - var1 days)*100 + day(current date - var1days))


Please tag db2-luw  , db2-400 , db2-zos depending on the Db2-server platform.   You can use a dynamic SQL block for this, depending on your authorization level.

Why do you need a view here at all? Why not to use just a simple cross join of these 2 tables?

because it's just an example , I have 14  queries like my 1st example to include X times in huge query

What's your db2 version and platform?
